# .NET does ORA-0001 multiple calls ORACLE

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, asp.net-mvc-3

I have noticed in .NET applications (MVC3 and Web Froms) that occasionaly certain called procedure executes multiple times. 
(it is very simple (link click) call so it is not problem in c#)
sample of link click code:

```
try{
     using (var context = new DB())
                {                                       
                    context.some_procedure(user_id, order_id, "string");
                }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     Log.Error("some_procedure " + ex.Message + ex.InnerException);
     return null;
}
```

In Oracle procedure is also taken care of duplicates.
I must add that columns iduser and idorder have pair unique index constraint on table1 (pair_unique_const)

```
some_procedure(number user_id, number order_id, varchar2 string)
.
.
.
    SELECT COUNT(*)
             INTO var_exists
             FROM table1 WHERE
             iduser = user_id and idorder = order_id;

IF var_exists = 0 then 

insert into table1 (id, iduser, idorder, text)
select(sequence.nextval, user_id, order_id, string);

Commit;

end if;
.
.
.
```

Still error ORA-0001 happens from time to time that suggests pair_unique_const (unique constraint index) is violated and duplicates could happen (if i havent put pair_unique_const).

No where else inserts are made into this table! 
So I assume .NET does multiple calls on click ocassionaly in a milisecond. 
Or can it be ODAC fault i don't know.

Since I have unique constraint on those 2 columns insert doesn't happen.
Also making a transaction call in c# and then commit when all is finished helped and solved the issue.

But I just want to know why this happens? 
click link call should make only one request.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are there multiple users using this web application at the same time? Then they could be inserting the same values in the same instant: both get a count of 0 and try to insert - one will fail.

Comment: There are multiple users of this web application but this can't be the case. Users are checked for their identity which is unique and also orders have id unique. I have added proper names of columnes so it is more self explenatory.